# Why can I clean my string with iconv(my_string,"UTF-8","UTF-8")?

Tags: r, utf-8, character-encoding, iconv

I'm loading french text from a csv. It contains characters such as 'é','ç' etc.

If I open it with notepad ++, some lines will display fine and some will display 'Ã©' instead of 'é', if I leave it in default ANSI encoding.

If I set it in UTF-8 encoding the French characters that displayed wrong now display right, and those that displayed right display wrong, so 'é' now becomes 'xE9' for example.

so it seems I cannot choose one specific encoding to load all of the file right.

By accident I realized that in R I can solve the issue for some lines by using iconv from AND to UTF-8, I'm wondering however why it works. I'm pulling my hair frequently because of character encoding in R so I'd like to reach a better understanding.

```
my_string <- substr(text_df$text[12718],91,121)  # "j'ai reÃ§u la semaine derniÃ¨re"
Encoding(my_string) # "unknown"
my_string <- iconv(my_string,"UTF-8","UTF-8")    # "j'ai reçu la semaine dernière"
Encoding(my_string) # "UTF-8"
```

*Note: it would work just as well for those lines to do:
    Encoding(my_string) <- "UTF-8"
as Cath mentions, but it would not return NA if the string was not an UTF8 string, see below.*

However It actually doesn't work for every line

```
my_string <- substr(text_df$text[2],56,67)  # "les intérêts"
iconv(my_string,"UTF-8","UTF-8") # NA
Encoding(my_string) <- "UTF-8"
my_string # "les int\xe9r\xeats"
```

So for those lines I use

```
my_string <- substr(text_df$text[2],56,67)         # "les intérêts"
my_string <- iconv(my_string,"LATIN1","LATIN1")    # "les intérêts"
# Encoding(my_string) <- "LATIN1" would do the same, but not return NA if the encoding isn't right so harder to control
my_string <- iconv(my_string,"LATIN1","UTF-8")
Encoding(my_string) # "UTF-8"
```

In the end to sort things out I use this ugly bit of script:

```
text_utf8 <- iconv(text_df$text,"UTF-8","UTF-8")
text_latin <- iconv(text_df$text,"LATIN1","LATIN1")
text_latin <- iconv(text_latin,"LATIN1","UTF-8")
any(is.na(text_utf8) & is.na(text_latin)) # FALSE so I don't need other encodings
text_df$text <- text_utf8
text_df$text[is.na(text_df$text)] <- text_latin[is.na(text_df$text)]
any(is.na(text_df$text)) # FALSE
table(Encoding(text_df$text))
#unknown   UTF-8 
#2727    9999
```

Is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: what happens if you just do `Encoding(my_string) <- "UTF-8"` ? I think `iconv` works only because you are telling R which Encoding to use, you don't really need `iconv` but just to define the right Encoding

Comment: Thanks Cath, your suggestion indeed works just as well when iconv works as well. They differ however when we guess the encoding wrong, in those cases iconv returns NA, which is easier to handle. I edited my question with the solution I found in the end, but I feel there has to be a better way to do it.

Comment: I think @Cath is spot on here: in case the encoding is already correct but R stores it as "unknown" (and wrongly tries to display it in the current locale), iconv() just declares the encoding instead of converting.